# Unable to merge nested arrays data in php

Tags: php, arrays

I try to merge the data's in the arrays in 'c' and 'a' inside `MYDATA` but is it possible? Some examples and tips would be helpful! I would love to hear from you!

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [MYDATA] => Array
            (
                [id] => 79
                [my_birth_day] => 1990-06-20
                [my_address] => 400
                [my_age] => 26
                [my_name] => Joy
                [my_id] => 1
                [created] => 2017-06-19 15:39:44
            )

        [c] => Array
            (
                [my_test] => math
            )

        [a] => Array
            (
                [my_date] => 2017-08-13
            )

    )
```

I would want the result to be like

```
[MYDATA] => Array
            (
                [id] => 79
                [my_birth_day] => 1990-06-20
                [my_address] => 400
                [my_age] => 26
                [my_name] => Joy
                [my_id] => 1
                [created] => 2017-06-19 15:39:44
                [my_test] => math
                [my_date] => 2017-08-13
```

Comment: You do know about [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

Comment: Do some google search before posting a question here..

Comment: Well, array_merge didn't work. No clear solution found in google.

Comment: *"didn't work"* is not a proper description of the problem you're facing. What doesn't work? What error do you get? What result do you get? More importantly, you're not showing us *how* you tried to do it. Where is your code? Please check [ask] and [mcve], then edit your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just merge the elements one by one:

```
<?php
$input = [
    'MYDATA' => [
        'id' => 79,
        'my_birth_day' => '1990-06-20',
        'my_address' => 400,
        'my_age' => 26,
        'my_name' => 'Joy',
        'my_id' => 1,
        'created' => '2017-06-19 15:39:44'
    ],
    'c' => [
        'my_test' => 'math'
    ],
    'a' => [
        'my_date' => '2017-08-13'
    ]
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($element) use (&$output) {
    $output = array_merge($output, $element);
});
print_r($output);
```

The order in which you iterate over the input array determines which entries will win in case you have key collisions.

---

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 79
    [my_birth_day] => 1990-06-20
    [my_address] => 400
    [my_age] => 26
    [my_name] => Joy
    [my_id] => 1
    [created] => 2017-06-19 15:39:44
    [my_test] => math
    [my_date] => 2017-08-13
)
```

Comment: OP's question does not show any research effort, no clear problem description and no code. Not sure if just throwing code at him is in the spirit of SO.

Answer (score 0):

The function needed is **array_merge()**, it takes an unlimited number of parameters, the order of the parameters dictates the order in which the arrays are merged, in this case it would not matter, but say you had matching keys, say two *'my_address'* keys the value from the last array defining this key will be returned as a result as the function call.

See the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Merge the inner arrays, assuming your outermost array is called **$array** you can try the following:

```
<?php 

$array = array(
    'MYDATA' => array(
        'id' => '79',
            'my_birth_day' => '1990-06-20',
            'my_address' => '400',
            'my_age' => '26',
            'my_name' => 'Joy',
            'my_id' => '1',
            'created' => '2017-06-19 15:39:44'
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'my_test' => 'math'
    ),
    'a' => array(
        'my_date' => '2017-08-13'
    )
 );

 $mergedMyData = array_merge($array['MYDATA'], $array['c'], $array['a']);

 //output the data
 print_r($mergedMyData);

 ?>
```

hope this helps

Comment: OP's question does not show any research effort, no clear problem description and no code. Not sure if answering such questions is in the spirit of SO.